# Visual Basic 6 Regex returning blank match

Tags: regex, vb6

I'm trying to get all the matched values from a string using:

```
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myMatch As match
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "(?=.*(0[1|2|7]{1}[0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{6}|0[1|2|7]{1}[0-9]{9}))"
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True

Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute("Contract faxed to 019962401797")
For Each myMatch In myMatches
  MsgBox (myMatch.value)
Next
```

From the string I'm after it returns '01992401797', although I get a match when I read `myMatch.value` it is blank.

I'm thinking it has something to do with my regex because if I change the pattern to 'Contact' it returns the word 'Contact' but I can get it to work for my number pattern.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html (?=) is zero-length. You aren't capturing anything...

Comment: Not great with regular expressions, but give `.*(0[1|2|7]{1}[0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{6}|0[1|2|7]{1}[0-9]{9})` a try. The phone is returned in the first submatch.

Comment: Thanks dda and jac - this worked a treat